# JSONP read text from exernal file

Tags: html, jsonp

Please help

I have external link with JSON object's , link: http://creativescream.com/html5ws/api/news.
Now i must to read json on my site but i can;t do that. I used to make my json file and that work ok but that is not a poent i must read JSON from external link.

I tried this code but it will not work:

```
     <script>
        $.getJSON("http://creativescream.com/html5ws/api/news",
        function(json){
            for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                var newsTitle = json.contents[i].title;
                var newsContent = json.contents[i].news;
                var newsAuthor = json.contents[i].author;
                var newsLink = json.contents[i].url;
                $("#latest_news").append("<h2>" + newsTitle + "</h2><br />");
                $("#latest_news").append("<p>" + newsContent + "</p><br /><a href='" + newsLink + "' target='_blank'>[Pročitaj opširnije]</a><br />");
                $("#latest_news").append("<span style='color: #000000; font-weight: bold;margin-left:10px; '>Author: " + newsAuthor + "</span><br /><br />");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The site isn't returning jsonp nor is jquery treating it as such.  Add ?callback=? to the end of the URL in order for jquery to treat it like jsonp and tell the server the function name to inject into the response.

Comment: How to tell server function name to inject into the response ?

Comment: jquery should fill it in if it sees the pattern callback=? in the url it will replace the ? with a uniquely generated function name.

Comment: I tried this but now when i run firebug i get this message **invalid label "status: ok"** .

Comment: I can't test the feed right now, but try browsing to http://creativescream.com/html5ws/api/news?callback=test in your browser and see if it adds test() around the json.  If not then the feed doesn't support jsonp and you will either have to create a relay service on your own domain to allow you to make external json requests, however you lose any session context so if the external feed requires a login this is not a valid solution or ask the service provider to add jsonp support.